# Php code inside a .jsp file is not working

Tags: php, html

My php code  inside a jsp file where it contains both html code and php code is not working. I want to dispay the the details from text file into a html table.My text looks like this,

> {"Issue Type":"Security","Description":"xyz","App
>   Name":"Whatsapp","Title":"abc","Issue Id":1}

I tried with the below code..

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Issue Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>App Name</th>
            <th>Issue Type</th>

        </tr>

        <?php
$file_handle = fopen("IssueDetails.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode(':', $line_of_text);
    echo "<tr><td >$parts[0]</td><td >$parts[1]</td><td >$parts[2]</td><td >$parts[3]</td><td >$parts[4]</td></tr>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
    </table>
```

Comment: .jsp is java servlet file, it has nothing to do with php.. save your files as .php instead

Comment: JSP is not PHP. They are not the same language, they are not compatible, you cannot mix them in the same file. Pick one or the other and stick with it.